# Typescript API Repositories and Unit of Work implementation (Domain-Driven Design)

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm trying to implement **Repositories** and the **Unit of Work** pattern using **Sequelize** and Typescript in the existing project, following **Domain-Driven Design**. However, I encountered some difficulties due to a lack of relevant examples on the internet.

Let's consider the following code example.

```
interface IPostRepo {
    save(post: Post): Promise<void>;
}

interface ICommentRepo {
    save(comment: Comment): Promise<void>;
    saveBulk(comments: Comment[]): Promise<void>;
}

class SequelizePostRepo implements IPostRepo {
    private models: any;
    private commentRepo: ICommentRepo;

    constructor(models: any, commentRepo: ICommentRepo) {
        this.models = models;
        this.commentRepo = commentRepo;
    }

    public async save(post: Post): Promise<void> {
        const PostModel = this.models.Post;
        const rawSequelizePost = await PostMap.toPersistence(post);

        await PostModel.create(rawSequelizePost);
        await this.commentRepo.saveBulk(comments);
    }
}

class SequelizeCommentRepo implements ICommentRepo {
    private models: any;

    constructor(models: any) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    async save(comment: Comment): Promise<void> {
        const CommentModel = this.models.Comment;
        const rawSequelizeComment = CommentMap.toPersistence(comment);

        await CommentModel.create(rawSequelizeComment);
    }

    async saveBulk(comments: Comment[]): Promise<void> {
        for (let comment of comments) {
            await this.save(comment);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The code is not complete and simplified for the problem demonstration purpose.

`IPostRepo` and `ICommentRepo` are contracts for the specific implementation such as `SequelizePostRepo` and `SequelizeCommentRepo`.
Both of them implement a basic save method that operates on **Domain Entities**: `Post` and `Comment`. The `Post` is the **Aggregate Root** (models object contains the essential Sequelize models definition).

```
class CreatePostWithComments implements UseCase {
    private postRepo: IPostRepo;

    constructor (postRepo: IPostRepo) {
        this.postRepo = postRepo;
    }

    public async execute (req: ReplyToPostDTO) {

        /**
         *
         * More logic related to post and comments creation goes here
         *
         */

        post.addComment(comment1);
        post.addComment(comment2);
        post.addComment(comment3);

        await this.postRepo.save(post);
    }
}
```

Having `CreatePostWithComments` **Use Case** in the end I want to save `Post` Aggregate with attached comments. I'd like to do it in a single MySQL transaction using the **Unit of Work** pattern correctly.

I would appreciate any help that indicates correct implementation using simple examples.

I found the following package: https://github.com/pilagod/uow-sequelize, however by virtue of documentation deficiency I don't know how to use it rightly.

Comment: I am looking into the same topic using the same stack, I didn't find anything solid yet but Postgres (which I am using) and Mysql both defines their transactions as a Unit of Work, I am not yet sure if sequelize leverage that.

If I didn't find anything solid, I will probably resort to testing the behavior myself and as for the uow-sequelize, I found it as well while searching for the topic, I didn't get to use it, but it seems to be deserted and of limited popularity so I'd steer away from it.

Comment: Took a quick look at the source code of `uow-sequelize` and `uow-template`, they seem to be a simple syntax sugar to apply the UOW pattern, which you could implement your self or just clone and build on top of it, they also have some tests (not sure about the coverage) so that's definitely a good start.

But I am still not confident if this actually satisfies the UOW from the technical aspect (push all commands in a single trip or no) or it's just an enabler to implement the design pattern in your code.

FYI the code is super trivial (a single file) to read or use.